# RF Design for ESP32 S3-based Custom Project

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, pcb-design, esp32, pcb-antenna

I'm currently working on a custom project using the ESP32 S3 SoC, and I'm facing some challenges with the RF design aspect. I'm relatively new to RF design and could use some guidance in optimizing the RF performance of my project.

Here's a brief overview of my project:

I'm using the ESP32 S3 SoC for my custom project, which involves wireless communication.
The project requires reliable RF performance, but I'm unsure about the best practices for RF design and antenna selection.
I'm particularly concerned about achieving optimal signal strength and minimizing interference in my design.
I've done some research on RF design principles, but I'm still not confident in my approach. I'm looking for advice from experienced RF engineers or anyone familiar with RF design for ESP32-based projects.

Here is my schematic diagram. I am using EasyEDA for design:

[image]

I need to find a proper matching circuit for this and achieve a 50-ohm impedance.

[image: Matching Circuit]

I have considered trace width as 0.83mm as per my understanding.

I am ordering PCB from JLCPCB with the following specifications: 4-layer PCB with a thickness of 1.6mm, inner copper weight of 0.5oz, and outer copper weight of 1oz.

I need help from the community to check my design and find the proper values for L1, C15, and C11. Thank you very much for your assistance.

[image]
-old board i designed which in which RF was not working because of many reasons like trace issue I used a dip switch in-between and many more only rf part is having issue please help out to fix this

Comment: _"I need help from the community to check my design and find the proper values for L1, C15, and C11"._ Unfortunately it does not work this way. For commercial design, we usually buy antenna from reputable manufacture on large quantity, in return the manufacturer offers antenna matching service for free or for a feee. When the PCB design is produced, we send a bare board to the antenna vendor, tell them the frequency and bandwidth we are expecting, they will do the antenna matching based on the part we order to decide the value for the pi circuit (L2, c19, c21) for the particular PCB design.

Comment: During PCB design, we also ned to make sure that the PCB trace and spaces need to match 50-ohm impedance (there are calculator available for most of the CAD tool you used for PCB design), during the manufacturing, you need to specific the board material and ask for "impedance match" for board fabrication.

Comment: Ceramic antenna is small but also particularly difficult to tune. If you are not design for large quantity production and only for hobby project, it is better to use ESP32-C3 module instead of ESP32-C3 chip. Another advantage of using module is that it is likely have gone through the EMI, FCC and other certifications that required to meet the regulatory requirements.